# How to see between windows 7 professional and enterprise machines?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, homegroup

I've got a desktop system running Windows 7 Professional and a laptop running windows 7 Enterprise in a domain-joined computer and I need to copy around 50 GB of files from the Enterprise machine to the professional one.  I'd rather not burn a bunch of DVDs or use my tiny flash drive of 1 GB to do the transfer.

How can I mount a drive from one of the computers to the other so that I can just drag and drop?  I tried using a homegroup, but the windows 7 Enterprise laptop does not see it from the professional desktop and the laptop cannot make its own homegroup since it belongs to a domain.  I also tried mounting a drive, but the other computer's name is not seen.  I also tried using ip address as in `\\192.168.1.100\c` but it fails too.

Comment: Have you tried the cmd command "[subst](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html)" ?

Comment: @Martin That does not work as I get the error `Path not found - \\myMachine\c'.  This is more an issue of how to see the other machine.

Comment: Anyone please comment on the -1 vote for this question so I can improve my future questions.

Comment: Don't know why that was voted down - seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this at home or work? Are both PCs on the same network? Once you have shared files on one PC open Windows Explorer on the second PC and click network in the left sidebar - this will show available PCs on the network. Even if you have not explicitly shared folders on the first PC you should still see it and Public Folders should be available.

Comment: This is at home but the Enterprise machine is a work laptop on my home network.  I need to get my personal photographs off that machine. In the network, on each machine, only itself is shown. I'm not able to see the other machine from either.

Comment: Do you have admin privilege on your work machine? If so you can temporarily change the network from work to home and then enable the homegroup.

Comment: If the work PC is really well locked down you might still be able to boot from a Linux live CD and share files - Linux Mint is a good choice

Comment: Can you please elaborate in your answer as to how one temporarily changes the network to home when you have Admin privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Your work-computer may very well be locked down by the domain admin, so:

On the home-computer, enable file-sharing.
Share the directory you like and make sure to give "everyone" read(/write) privileges.
Find out the ip-address of the home computer, i.e 192.168.1.101.
From the work-computer, connect to \192.168.1.101\sharename
Copy the files you like.

Answer (score 1):

To mount a drive, you can:

1. Share a drive on one of the computer by going to:
   Computer>right-click drive>sharing>advanced sharing>share this
   folder
2. To mount it on the other computer, go to Computer>Map Network Drive (bar on top)>enter
   location

A great tool for moving large files between computers is [Teracopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) (free version is fine).

If they are on different networks then this won't work. You'd have to either set up a VPN, or use a remote login tool like UltraVNC.

Comment: I had tried this too already, I am unable to see the other computer from either end.

Comment: @WilliamKF - Worked for me.  You must be doing it wrong.